# How do you create a role in discord.js

Tags: discord, bots, discord.js

Hello I'm trying to make a role but I don't know-how.

Here is my code at the moment:

```js
guild.roles.create({
    data: {
        name: 'muted',
        permission {
            SEND_MESSAGES: false,
            ADD_REACTION: false
        }
    }
})
```

It says guild is not defined help. It is for my mute command.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use:

```js
message.guild.roles.create({
    data: {
        name: 'muted',
        permissions: {
            SEND_MESSAGES: false,
            ADD_REACTIONS: false
        }
    }
});
```